# UIBinder and MVP in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, uibinder

When using the MVP pattern as described [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html) in GWT, how do you create a presenter associated with a view when the view is part of another uibinder-defined view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You instantiate it yourself via:

1. `@UiFactory` method:

   ```
   @UiFactory
   public Widget getMyView(){

       // here you instantiate your view & activity
       ...

       // your view contais a widget or is a widget
       return widget
   }
   ```
2. `@UiField(provided=true)` field :

   ```
   @UiField(provided=true)
   public Widget myView;

   // then instantiate it in constructor
   ```